# Redis remote connection security concern

Tags: php, node.js, redis

I'm using Redis to store PHP sessions to have an access to them in Node.js through the same server. How can I ensure that the client connection to redis is restricted to localhost only ? I afraid someone will connect to my Redis server in a remote connection and gain an access to this sensitive data. Is that already secured by default ?

Comment: Please read http://redis.io/topics/security, what you are asking about is explained very clearly there.

Comment: /etc/redis/redis.conf

Comment: Hi Pawal, thank you for your reply. So basically I need to add 'bind 127.0.0.1' to the redis.conf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://redis.io/topics/security

> Note that it is possible to bind Redis to a single interface by adding a line like the following to the redis.conf file:
>
> > bind 127.0.0.1

It's also recommended to configure your firewall to close whatever port redis is listening on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I configure the redis.conf file and add the 'bind 127.0.0.1' and block the port redis is listening on through the firewall, I can feel safe, right ?

Comment: It won't be possible to connect to the redis server externally anymore, but obviously if someone managed to get your SSH login and login to the server via SSH they would be able to access redis.